# Access variable by string in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, eval

I want to access and update state of variable.

```
function valueChange(sourceVariable, targetVariable, sourceUnit) {
    $scope[targetVariable] = measure($scope[sourceVariable] + sourceUnit + ".").kilograms();        
});
```

This function is called whenever something is entered in input field (on tab out). But the problem is value in input field that is bound to $scope[targetVariable] is not updated until you click inside input box.

PS: If I use variable in regular fashion it works fine.

Comment: Can you attache a jsbin sample or html update question with html part where you bind $scope[targetVariable] with input?

Comment: <input ng-model="details.model.NetWeightImperial" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'change blur', debounce: 0 }"  type="text">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to udpate your variable inside `$scope.$apply`:

```
function valueChange(sourceVariable, targetVariable, sourceUnit) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
          $scope[targetVariable] = measure($scope[sourceVariable] + sourceUnit + ".").kilograms();      
    });  
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, i had error with variable names also.